# Value of Observable is not displayed when it is 0 (Zero)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

Using Angular 8, I have the following:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(count$ | async) as count; else loader">{{count}}</ng-container>
<ng-template #loader>
    loading
</ng-template>
```

The variable `count$` is an `Observable<number>` ...

When `count$` value is `1`, `2`, etc the value is correctly displayed.

But when the `count$` value is `0` it shows only `loading`.

Any idea why?

Comment: 0 is a falsy value, your `ngIf` evaluates to false so it shows the `else` condition, hence displaying `loading`.

Comment: What would be the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to test the value of the observable in a condition and also display that value in the view, you can use two nested `ng-container` tags. The first one gets the `count` value (using a technique explained in [this article](https://medium.com/@yurykatkov/how-to-avoid-multiple-async-pipes-in-angular-ff0d51a8d368)), and the second one uses the value in the condition and in the view. This structure allows to reuse the value without creating multiple subscriptions to the same observable.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ count: count$ | async } as data">
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.count === 0 || data.count > 0; else loader">
    {{data.count}}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loader>
  loading
</ng-template>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ob8xmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Answer (score -1):

Because it is falsy value: `Boolean(0) === false`. Nothing special ;)

UPD:

.ts

```
this.count$;

constructor() {
  this.count$ = interval(2000).pipe(map(i => `${i}`));
}
```

.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="count$ | async as count; else loader">
  {{ count }}
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loader>
  loading
</ng-template>
```

Comment: And what is the solution?

Comment: With your code, what happens when `count$` is `undefined`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I have updated the solution. Yes, in prev version content of the template won't be rendered, you are right. Please, check the update.

Comment: It's only show the "problem", but not the solution.